# Failed to set object property value when it is defined as [key in keyof T]

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement a function to pick properties of an object. the function was

```
const project = function<T>(object: T, projection: Projection<T>): Partial<T> {
    throw new Error("not implemented yet");
};
```

The definition of `Projection<T>` was

```
type Projection<T> = {
    [key in keyof T]?: 1 | 0
};
```

Something like MongoDB `project` operation. User can pass `{_id: 1, name: 1}` so that we picked `id` and `name` from the `object`.

When I tried to create another function which allows user to specify one property to project, I got the following error.

```
const project_one_property = function<T, K extends keyof T>(object: T, propertyName: K): Partial<T> {
    //    Type '{ [x: string]: number } is not assignable to type 'Projection<T>'.
    //    vvvvvvvvvv
    const projection: Projection<T> = {
        [propertyName]: 1
    };
    return project(object, projection);
};
```

I don't know why this error occurred since the type of `propertyName` should be `key of T` and `Projection<T>` allows keys from the key of `T`.

What I can do to make this function works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler appears to infer `{ [x: string]: number; }` for any object literal that uses a computed property name. You could use a type assertion to `any` on the object literal. Or you could initialize the value in two steps:

```
const projection: Projection<T> = {};
projection[propertyName] = 1;
```

Comment: You can also use type assertion to `Projection<T>` without `any`: `const projection = { [propertyName]: 1 } as Projection<T>;`